# Custom Block in Megento not working on live server

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have a block in my site which is working fine in local host but when I have uploaded it to Linux sever its not working. I have gone through other suggestions to have same case in file name and paths but its not applicable.

Please review the code and let me know where I am missing something

1. Adding new module

   app/etc/modules/sciffer_All.xml

   ```
    <config>
        <modules>
        <sciffer_recentproducts>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </sciffer_recentproducts>
        </modules>
    </config>
   ```
2. Config.xml

   app/code/local/sciffer/recentproducts/etc/config.xml

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <config>
    <modules>
        <sciffer_build>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </sciffer_build>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
                <build>
                    <class>sciffer_build_Block</class>
                </build>
        </blocks>
        <models>
                <build>
                    <class>sciffer_build_Model</class>
                </build>
        </models>
    <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
                <observers>
                    <sciffer_build_log_cart_add>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>build/Observer</class>
                        <method>checkQuantity</method>
                    </sciffer_build_log_cart_add>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>

        </events>
    </global>
    </config>
   ```
3. Block/recentproducts.php

   app/code/local/sciffer/recentproducts/Block/recentproducts.php

   ```
   class sciffer_recentproducts_Block_recentproducts extends            Mage_Core_Block_Template
    {
     public function getRecentProducts()
    {
          $arr_categorys=array();
          $categorys=Mage::getModel("recentproducts/recentproducts")->getRecentProducts();
          foreach($categorys as $category)
          {
            $arr_categorys[]=array(
            'id'=>$category->getId(),
            'name'=> $category->getName(),
            'url'=>$category->getUrl($category),
            'menu'=>!$category->getIncludeInMenu());
           }
           return $arr_categorys;

       }
    }
   ```
4. Module/recentproducts.php

   app/code/local/sciffer/recentproducts/Module/recentproducts.php

   ```
   class sciffer_recentproducts_Model_recentproducts extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
   {
    public function getRecentProducts()
    {  

        $categorys=Mage::getModel("catalog/category")
            ->getCollection()
            //->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('is_active')
            ->addUrlRewriteToResult()
            ->setOrder('entity_id','DESC')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('level',2)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu',0);

        return $categorys;
    }
   }
   ```
5. Frontend File recentproducts.phtml

   App/design/frontend/base/default/template/recentproducts/recentproducts.phtml

   ```
   <p>HEllo</p>
   ```
6. After creating all files, I have created a CMS page and added code to content to show block

   ```
     {{block type="recentproducts/recentproducts"name="recentproducts_recentproducts"template="recentproducts/recentproducts.phtml"}}
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to uppercase the first letter of your folder. like sciffer will be Sciffer and same for the recentroducts, so that autoloader can find the path.

Comment: Sorry man.but after changing first letter to caps than also nothing happens its working on local system but not in server

Comment: also make first letter caps of recentproducts.php, also in your 4th point you typed it Module, make it Model then try.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in question.thats correct in code.But yes your suggestion was right.First Letter in capital worked.Thank You